# Keyboard Hooks to disable it globally in C#

Tags: c#, keyboard, keyboard-hook

Anybody knows how can disable keyboard globally developing hooks in C#?

I have a source code that implements a hook to disable the keyboard in the same application but if I execute it and the keyboard was working in an text editor don't work it (I can keep writing) in Windows 7. I would like capture/disable the keyboard globally (for all applications that are running). My intention is to lock it completely for Windows 7.

This is my hook code:

```
globalKeyboardHook gkh = new globalKeyboardHook();

/// <summary>
/// Installs the global hook
/// </summary>
public void hook() {
    IntPtr hInstance = LoadLibrary("User32");
    hhook = SetWindowsHookEx(WH_KEYBOARD_LL, hookProc, hInstance, 0);
}


public int hookProc(int code, int wParam, ref keyboardHookStruct lParam) {
    //indicates if any of underlaing events set e.Handled flag
    bool handled = false;
    IntPtr lFakeParam = new IntPtr(lParam.vkCode);

    if ((code >= 0) && (KeyDown != null || KeyUp != null || wParam == WM_SYSKEYDOWN || wParam == WM_SYSKEYUP))
    {
        //read structure KeyboardHookStruct at lParam
        keyboardHookStruct MyKeyboardHookStruct = (keyboardHookStruct)Marshal.PtrToStructure(lFakeParam, typeof(keyboardHookStruct));
        Keys keyData = (Keys)MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode;

        KeyEventArgs e = new KeyEventArgs(keyData);

        log.Debug("cached wParam = [" + wParam + "] vkCode = [" + MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode + "] flags = [" + MyKeyboardHookStruct.flags + "]");

        if (MyKeyboardHookStruct.vkCode == 144)
        {
            // NUMLOCK
            handled = false;
        }

        KeyDown(this, e);
    }
    //if event handled in application do not handoff to other listeners
    if (handled)
    {
        SendKeys.Send("{NUMLOCK}");
        SendKeys.Send("{NUMLOCK}");
        return 1;
        //return CallNextHookEx(hKeyboardHook, nCode, wParam, lFakeParam);
    }
    else
    {
        return CallNextHookEx(hhook, code, wParam, ref lParam);
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your declaration for the hookproc delegate is wrong.  The return value is IntPtr, not int.  Same for the wParam argument.  You don't handle the lParam argument correctly, it is already a reference to the struct and using lParam.vkCode produces nonsense.  Google sample code to get this right.

Comment: Thanks @HansPassant but I tried that and the problem is the same, in HookProc function definition accepts (int (int,int, IntPtr target). It works in Windows XP but in Windows 7 I don't know why but it have some problems (it fails sometimes).